# How to use output of LSTM and reshaping

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

This is how I built and compiled my LSTM model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(40, input_shape=(24, 12), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
from keras import optimizers
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-10, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam, metrics=['mae'])
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20),
         ModelCheckpoint(filepath='LSTM.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]
```

Now when I executed it via
`history=model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=15, epochs=50, validation_split=0.1, verbose=2,callbacks=callbacks)`

where
X_train was initially shaped (10000, 12) which I re-shaped to (10000, 24, 12) so that model.fit could work without error.
Y_train was shape (10000, 12). No problem till now.

Problem started when I am using below

`estimated_result = model.predict(X_train)`  - (is prediction like this wrong?)

`errors = sum(abs(estimated_result-Target_output))  The estimated_result shape is (10000, 1) and Target_output shape (10000, 12))`

```
final errors = sum(errors != 0)
print(final errors)
```

Final errors are coming to be the same no matter whatever input parameters to the code is. I suspect the way I used model.predict is wrong. How do I use the result of LSTM for the error formula?

Also how to correctly re-shape X_train to (10000, 24, 12)? I suspect if the model.predict is not wrong the reshaping might be!!
Please advise what is incorrectly done. Thanks in advance

Comment: ... should you print the mse instead? Most floating point numbers are not zero.

Comment: what is a nature of your data ? Is it a long sequence ?

Comment: @Andrey It is random data

Comment: @user202729 I have to count the number of block errors, in the end, thus I need the final errors value for that

Comment: What do you mean by "block error"? The output is a floating point value, no?

Comment: @MathResearcher print out the final errors. Are they absolutely the same or just similar ? If you use random data - they should be similar but not absolutely the same

Comment: @user202729 A block error is a common type of error in certain types of digital television transmission, particularly those that use image compression. So whole number. My data is random data not image though.

Comment: @Andrey valid point! The error (as I mentioned is the whole number) and exactly the same which is weird and I do not understand why. What part of coding went wrong?

Comment: The point I am curious about is - 'Is model.predict used correctly? Have I missed a step while using the results of LSTM (after model fitting)'. Also, have I reshaped correctly?

Comment: Can someone please suggest what is wrong in the coding?